# Invertible matrices

Tags: matrices

Please help with the next question.

Let A and B be two invertible matrices such that $A+B \neq 0$.
Prove or disprove that A+B is invertible.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your attempts so far?

Comment: This is true for $1\times 1$ matrices over any field, false in general for $n\times n$ matrices of size $n\geq 2$... I think you should look for a counterexample yourself.

Comment: A more challenging problem, I think, is to show it when neither matrix is diagonal.

Comment: @user99680 You mean something like $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can conclude with these matrices?

$$A=I_2\ \text{and}\ B=\mathrm{diag}(-1,1)$$

Comment: Great! A and B are both invertible ($A^{-1}=A \ , \ B^{-1}=B $), $A+B \neq 0$ and A+B is definitely not invertible.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope you're got Allah's rahmat in solving the serious problem. +1